# Is it OK to use Wireshark on Tails?

Tags: tails

While Tails has aircrack-ng, it does not have Wireshark installed by default. Can Wireshark hurt my anonimity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the [official documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/additional_software/index.en.html) on installing additional software and the warnings that it includes.